# Set value of SharePoint Angular People Picker Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I am using the following directive in a create form and am able to capture and store the values into SharePoint via REST: https://github.com/jasonvenema/sharepoint-angular-peoplepicker

I am using this as follows within my HTML:

```
<sp-people-picker name="CC" id="CC" ng-model="vm.cc" min-entries="1" max-entries="20" allow-duplicates="false" show-login="false" show-title="true" min-characters="2" app-web-url="$scope.spAppWebUrl" />
```

However, now I need to have the values selected in the create form display in my update form. I have tried setting the scope as follows, where vm.cc is the model for my directive, but it doesn't work as I believe the directive doesn't resolve the values unless they are typed into the form:

```
$scope.vm.cc = {
            Email: "myemail@email.com",
            Login: "i:0#.f|membership|myemail@macrosoft.org",
            Name: "Lastname, firstname"
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can have the values populated in my update form on load? I could see this potentially requiring some sort of resolution of the stored values occurring on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the directive mentioned in my original post, I was able to update the field values by calling this method:

```
peoplePicker.RecipientSelected("i:0#.f|membership|myname@email.org", "Smith, Bob M", "bsmith@email.org");
```

You can also remove selected users in the field via:

```
peoplePicker.DeleteProcessedUser('i:0#.f|membership|myname@email.org);
```

Comment: How did you manage to get peoplePicker instance inside of your controller ? could you post your code ? thx